# Installed new Tor and now search engine is DISCONNECT search instead of Startpage

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, help

I just reinstalled Tor and the default search engine is not Startpage, it is DISCONNECT Search.  Did I install a bogus Tor browser?  And if not, why the change from Startpage?

Comment: I had Startpage and I want it back.
I don't have disconnect so your instructions above don't seem to work for me. Is there a more direct way to change the default search provider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did most likely not download a bogus tor browser bundle if you downloaded from official download links, some time back they switched.

> [New Search Provider](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-45-released#Search)
>
> Our default search provider has also been changed to Disconnect.
>   Disconnect provides private Google search results to Tor users without
>   Captchas or bans.

---

If you still have concerns then download again and verify your download.

https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html

Answer (score 0):

You most probably didn't download a bogus version of Tor Browser Bundle, but some 4.5 (or later) version. As [Stig Atle wrote](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/7075/88), the developers changed the default search engine.

You can easily move back to StartPage. At the search window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>) there is a small arrow right of the Disconnect D icon. If you click on it a menu opens and shows you all possibilities. Just choose StartPage and every search in this sessions uses StartPage.